# How to configure JBoss to grant acess to an port only to an specific IP

Tags: networking, jboss, port, wildfly

I am using Wildfly and trying to configure it to grant access to the port X only for the IP a.b.c.d, there is a way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interfaces and socket binding to bind a port against a specific interface like this:

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="public">
   <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="myInterface">
   <inet-address value="192.168.100.1"/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
  ...
  <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}" interface="myInterface/>
  ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess this is not exactly what I want to do. set an IP as inet-addres allow other people to access my service using this IP, what I want to do is to allow an specific computer - that isn't mine - to access the service in my computer, and reject requests coming from other computers.

Comment: In that case it is not a WildFly feature. You might use iptables (Linux) to restrict access to your instance by IP. You can set a source and destination address/port for this. Otherwise you can only add authentication or use SSL certificates

Comment: hm, now I understand, Thanks for the help @wfink